# Android studio emulator some black screen

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

When I use an android studio emulator I have some black pixels on the screen,
I try to delete the emulator and download another one but I have the same problem.

[[image: Image 1]]

[[image: Image 2]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue with my Android emulator. I fixed it by changing the Emulated Performance option of the emulator to "Software" from "Hardware". You can find this setting by editing your emulator using the pencil button in the Device Manager, and then the setting is under "Verify Configuration".

Comment: Yes and don't forget to restart the emulator.